# Google Cloud Monitoring Api - 400 One or more TimeSeries could not be written Duplicate TimeSeries encountered

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to push multiple data points to a timeseries ,  but every time I go to create  the next data point it pulls the previous iteration  along the current iteration. for example below

```
metric {
  type: "custom.googleapis.com/test/Cost_time"
}
resource {
  type: "global"
  labels {
    key: "project_id"
    value: "project-id-name"
  }
}
points {
  interval {
    end_time {
      seconds: 1594058659
    }
  }
  value {
    double_value: 0.044661431106760574
  }
}

[metric {
  type: "custom.googleapis.com/test/Cost_Time"
}
resource {
  type: "global"
  labels {
    key: "project_id"
    value: "project-id-name"
  }
}
points {
  interval {
    end_time {
      seconds: 1594058659
    }
  }
  value {
    double_value: 0.044661431106760574
  }
}
]
metrics are successfully sent
FINISHED <- works perfectly fine here
this is the iterator: 1
This the response keys: 0.0004929316673951689
Here is the result: 0.0004929316673951689
metric {
  type: "custom.googleapis.com/test/Cost_Time"
}
resource {
  type: "global"
  labels {
    key: "project_id"
    value: "project -id-name"
  }
}
points {
  interval {
    end_time {
      seconds: 1594058660
    }
  }
  value {
    double_value: 0.0004929316673951689
  }
}

[metric {
  type: "custom.googleapis.com/test/Cost_Time"
}
resource {
  type: "global"
  labels {
    key: "project_id"
    value: "project-id-name"
  }
}
points {
  interval {
    end_time {
      seconds: 1594058659
    }
  }
  value {
    double_value: 0.044661431106760574 <- duplicate is found here
  }
}
, metric {
  type: "custom.googleapis.com/test/Cost_Time"
}
resource {
  type: "global"
  labels {
    key: "project_id"
    value: "project-id-name"
  }
}
points {
  interval {
    end_time {
      seconds: 1594058660
    }
  }
  value {
    double_value: 0.0004929316673951689
  }
}
]
```

here is python code im using to iterate through a list of dictionary keys

```
 response_keys = list(response.keys())
    print(response_keys)
    for k in range(len(response_keys)):
        print("this is the iterator: " + str(k))
        print("This the response keys: " + str(response_keys[k]))
        getresp = get_time_series(response_keys[k])
        timeseries.append(getresp)
        print(timeseries)
        client.create_time_series("projects/project-name", timeseries)
        print("Cost metrics are successfully sent")
        print("FINISHED")
```

here the method Im using to create a time series

```
def get_time_series(result):
    series = monitoring_v3.types.TimeSeries()
    series.metric.type = 'custom.googleapis.com/test/Cost'
    series.resource.type = 'global'
    series.resource.labels['project_id'] = "project-name"
    points = series.points.add()
    points.interval.end_time.seconds = int(time.time())
    points.value.double_value = result
    return series
```

I have read and followed the documentation but my progress with this has come to a halt . Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Here is the full Stacktrace :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Field timeSeries[1] had an invalid value: Duplicate TimeSeries encountered. Only one point can be written per TimeSeries per request.: timeSeries[1]"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1594133230.854639000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.12.202:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Field timeSeries[1] had an invalid value: Duplicate TimeSeries encountered. Only one point can be written per TimeSeries per request.: timeSeries[1]","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/cost.py", line 108, in <module>
    print(main())
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/cost.py", line 103, in main
    client.create_time_series("projects/project-id-name", timeseries)
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/gapic/metric_service_client.py", line 1060, in create_time_series
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/malcode/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Field timeSeries[1] had an invalid value: Duplicate TimeSeries encountered. Only one point can be written per TimeSeries per request.: timeSeries[1]
```

Comment: hi, what is the actual error that you see from API ?

Comment: @c69 hello I edited my post

Comment: @c69 from what I surmised from the error is that there are too many points happening  at one point in time , which I guess begs the question whether if its possible to stagger a data points.